# Automate JavaScript Interop in Dart

Tags: dart, auto-generate, dart-js-interop

When using a third-party JavaScript library in my Dart project, I manually go through the library's documentation and iterate through its properties and methods to build the Dart code through a series of tedious `context` and `callMethod` calls.  **Has anyone figured out a way to automate this?**

I tried to first find a command-line interface that introspects the JavaScript library so that I can auto-generate the Dart source code.  I've been unsuccessful in my search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introspecting JS lib can be really hard due to the dynamic face of the JS language.

In the Typescript world there are `*.d.ts` files used to provide types to existing libraries. As far as I can tell most of those files are manually writen.

*For now* such a tool isn't yet available.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to make my implementation of .d.ts -> dart2js annotations converter.

This is possible way to automate the process.

Please, see https://github.com/denis-aes/DefinitelyTyped.dart